# Asp.net Textbox Empty on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox, postback

I am trying to create a Login Page.Whenever, I click on login button username textbox's text becomes empty.
I have tried :

1. Using Updatepanel didnt work
2. OnClientClick- it doesnt fires OnClick event
3. I tried getting value by string usrnm=Page.Request.Form["username"].ToString(); but it gave null value
4. I tried putting AutoPostBack="true" on textbox

Heres by markUp:

```
<label for="username">Username</label>
<%--<input type="text" name="Uname" id="username"/>--%>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtusrnm" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="Pname" id="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
<hr class="hr-sm hr-stroke" />
<div class="form-group">
   <%--<input id="btnlogin" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-wide" value="Login" runat="server" onserverclick="btnlogin_ServerClick"  >--%>
   <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-wide" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" EnableViewState="true" />
```

Comment: Make sure that you are not clearing your textbox on page load event of page.

Comment: Yes, please add the code present in the Page_Load event and in the button click

Comment: my `Page_Load` event is blank

Comment: You are talking about `Form["username"]`. But `username` does not exist. So of course it is null. Use `string user = txtusrnm.Text;` in code behind.

Comment: @VDWWD i have also tried the same but it gives blank not null

Comment: @mark you need to understand PostBacks, if you want to retain the value at the very least, assign the value to a Session Variable..

Comment: but again for that I would be needing value in textbox on Button Click, right?

Comment: there are many ways to do this.. JavaScript, UpdatePanel, do some googling on Partial Postbacks, or javascript or `__DoPostBack` method or `ViewState`

Comment: @mark, that is the most basic stuff of webforms. So as long as you are not doing something weird the values should be accessible.

Comment: What are you doing? First of all edit your post following guide lines and posting more code. Then, if you are using webforms, please use all that framework give to you. So please don't use input but textbox/button. Remove UseSubmitBehavior="false" EnableViewState="true": not needed, Moreover, there is a Login control in asp.net Webforms: if you are not using it to use bootstrap it's ok.

Comment: @Emanuele i removed both now it holds the value in textbox but its not firing click event

Comment: Add all code asp and behind, please @mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve my issue , i was having `AutoPostBack='true'` in textbox so just removed and also replace  `UseSubmitBehavior="false" EnableViewState="true"` with `CausesValidation="False"` , works fine now.

Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtusrnm" runat="server"/>
```

and button :

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-wide" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" CausesValidation="False"/>
```

Thanks